# Search Another Type Text SQL Server VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a problem with search: how do I search our language text from SQL query and which type data I select

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
cmd.Connection = cn
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table_12 WHERE m='" & "دولت خان" & "'"

Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim table As New DataTable()
adapter.Fill(table)

If table.Rows.Count() > 0 Then
        TextBox2.Text = table.Rows(0)(1).ToString()
        MessageBox.Show("Record found!")
Else
        MessageBox.Show("Record not found!")
```

Comment: What goes wrong? Do you get an error message or something else?

Comment: Your code is wide open to sql injection. You need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries before [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/) comes to visit.

Comment: @AndrewMorton on the contrary. The problem doesn't matter. This code is wide open to sql injection. It should be parameterized.

Comment: @gul; Please mark the answer if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your database objects local so you can control that they are closed and disposed. A single `Using...End Using` block handles this for you.

You can pass your connection string directly to the constructor of the connection and pass the command text and connection directly to the constructor of the command.

Always use parameters to avoid Sql Injection. The value concatenated to an sql command string is potentially executable. Parameter values are not.

```
Private Sub OpCode()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table_12 WHERE m= @m;", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@m", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = "دولت خان"
        cn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    If dt.Rows.Count() > 0 Then
        TextBox2.Text = dt.Rows(0)(1).ToString()
        MessageBox.Show("Record found!")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Record not found!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Search with like clause for unicode in column m and show column o:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT o FROM Table_12 WHERE m like N'%" & "دولت خان" & "%'"
```

Comment: Not Working i have two column name is m and o  data type is nvarchar(50)

Comment: you have not two columns with the same name, It's impossible in SQL Server.
So please share the schema of Table_12

Comment: it mean my first col name is m and second col name is o

Comment: which one do you want to search for?

Comment: i want search دولت خان then the second column data will show in textbox

Comment: Select Like in column m and show column o: 
"SELECT o FROM Table_12 WHERE m like N'%" & "دولت خان" & "%'"

Comment: my column name is (m) (o)  i have two column

Comment: I'm sure SQL injection is the last concern of him.

Comment: Just because they don't care about such a huge security problem doesn't mean you shouldn't try to steer them to a better approach.